# Fitting the Cluster Number Based on the Centroid

Tags: matlab, sorting, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm working with k-means in MATLAB. Here is my code:

```
load cobat.txt;  % read the file

k=input('Enter a number: ');        % determine the number of cluster
isRand=0;   % 0 -> sequeantial initialization
            % 1 -> random initialization

[maxRow, maxCol]=size(cobat);
if maxRow<=k, 
    y=[m, 1:maxRow];
else
    % initial value of centroid
    if isRand,
        p = randperm(size(cobat,1));      % random initialization
        for i=1:k
            c(i,:)=cobat(p(i),:) ; 
        end
    else
        for i=1:k
           c(i,:)=cobat(i,:);        % sequential initialization
        end
    end

    temp=zeros(maxRow,1);   % initialize as zero vector
    u=0;
    while 1,
        d=DistMatrix3(cobat,c);   % calculate the distance 
        [z,g]=min(d,[],2);      % set the matrix g group

        if g==temp,             % if the iteration doesn't change anymore
            break;              % stop the iteration
        else
            temp=g;             % copy the matrix to the temporary variable
        end
        for i=1:k
            f=find(g==i);
            if f                % calculate the new centroid 
                c(i,:)=mean(cobat(find(g==i),:),1)
            end
        end
        c
        sort(c)
    end

    y=[cobat,g]
```

"cobat" is the file of mine. Here it looks:

```
65  80  55
45  75  78
36  67  66
65  78  88
79  80  72
77  85  65
76  77  79
65  67  88
85  76  88
56  76  65
```

"c" is the variable of centroid (the central of the cluster) per each cluster. "g" is the variable to show the cluster number. The problem is, I want to sort/fit the cluster number (small to big) based on the centroid (c). So, I try to sort(c), but it doesn't affect to the cluster number (g).

When I try to sort(g), it's sorted just not like what I want. I want the cluster number is sorted based on the centroid. Example; when I run the code with k=3, here is the final centroid

```
 73.0000   79.0000   70.6667 %C 1
 58.3333   73.3333   84.6667 %C 2
 36.0000   67.0000   66.0000 %C 3
```

When I sort it, the number cluster is also "sorted",

```
36.0000   67.0000   66.0000 %C 3
58.3333   73.3333   70.6667 %C 2
73.0000   79.0000   84.6667 %C 1
```

I want it the number cluster is fit, like this.

```
36.0000   67.0000   66.0000 %C 1
58.3333   73.3333   70.6667 %C 2
73.0000   79.0000   84.6667 %C 3
```

It's fit, not sorted, so when this line 'y=[cobat,g]' is run, it changes too.

This seems easy, but tricky. I couldn't figure out. Anyone have any idea to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sorted indices returned from `sort` or `sortrow`

```
[B,index] = sortrows( c );  % sort the centroids
g = g(index(end:-1:1)); % arrange the labels based on centroids' order
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Where do I put that script?
I put it after this line: `sort(c)`, it's error. I try another place (before `y=[cobat,g]` line), it's getting error for the same thing: 
`??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in ==> clustere at 49
        c = c(index);`

Your answer will be so helpful and appreciated a lot. :)

Comment: these lines should replace the sorting you are currently doing. if you are using `sort` rather than `sortrows` than use `[g index] = sort(g); c = c(index);`

Comment: thank you again for the answer. :) i have tried, the error is still the same: `??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in ==> clustere at 47
       c = c(index);` It said "exceeds matrix dimension". My file has 3 dimension, so how to make that code fit in to 3 dimension? :)

Comment: @AlviSyahrin run in debug and see what is the size of `index`. Could it be that you sort the centroids not be row?

Comment: I have sortrows(), but it's just the same. Remember that I want the cluster number (g) is sorted based on the centroid (c) position. So, when `y=[cobat,g]` is run, it doesn't have to be sorted. I want the cluster number is fit the position the centroid. You have any idea?

Comment: @AlviSyahrin - It seems like I confused `g` and `c` in my answer. I edited it now - make sure I did not make any other mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, your script is working, but it's just like the one of under this line `When I sort it, the number cluster is also "sorted"`. I want the cluster number is fit the cluster number. I want the cluster number is changed based on the centroid. The cluster number is not 'sorted', it's changed, it fits on the centroid. :) Your script is almost there, hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Show the last example, I want it to be like that. Thank you!

Comment: the line `g = g(index);` is the one that should do the trick for you - it re-arranges the cluster number `g` according to the order of `B` (the sorted centroids).

Comment: So, what should I do next? I want the cluster number to be changed when it runs `y=[cobat,g]`

Comment: Yes, I've seen the `g=g(index)` result, but it's just the same with this line example `When I sort it, the number cluster is also "sorted"` :(

Comment: So it doesn't give any effect to `y=[cobat,g]` :(

Comment: @AlviSyahrin try `g = index(g);`

Comment: Have tried. The cluster number is still the same, it hasn't changed as its position. :( Thank you so much for your help though. :)

Comment: @Tae-SungShin I corrected the answer. thanks for your input,

Comment: That's not what I meant. **index** you got by sorting centroids are **destination** rather than something that would transform the indices you got from kmeans to sorted index. Just simple thinking would give you a clear idea. Another index acquired by resorting the index again would give the transform you wanted.